# Adicionar uma coluna nova em uma tabela e já preencher a coluna com os dados de uma coluna já existente na tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-html

Olá, estou precisando adicionar uma nova coluna em uma tabela, mas no momento de adicionar a coluna quero preencher os registros já existentes com os dados de um campo que já existe na tabela, segue exemplo:

tabela1
campo id

nessa tabela existe 10 registros com o campo id preenchido com 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10(cada qual no seu registros)

Quero adicionar o campo novo_id e no momento da criação do novo campo preencher novo_id com os dados do campo id, ficando assim após a criação do campo.

> id       novo_id 
> 1        1
> 2        2
> 3        3
> 4        4
> 5        5
> 6        6
> 7        7
> 8        8
> 9        9
> 10     10

ai depois disso vou fazer um alto incremente diferente na coluna novo_id, então se inserir um novo registro ficaria por exemplo:

> id       novo_id 
> 1        1
> 2        2
> 3        3
> 4        4
> 5        5
> 6        6
> 7        7
> 8        8
> 9        9
> 10     10
> 11     20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso você terá que primeiro adicionar a coluna e depois realizar um `update` com valor do campo `ID`.

[ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) para adicionar a coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabela1
ADD COLUMN novo_id integer NOT NULL;
```

(opcional) ou já adicionar a coluna com [auto incremento](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

```
ALTER TABLE Tabela1
ADD COLUMN novo_id SERIAL;
```

Depois disso você realiza o [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) atualizando o `novo_id` com o `Id` atual:

```
UPDATE Tabela1 
    SET novo_id = id
```

Se você adicionou o novo campo como auto incremento, você pode [setar o valor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) do `novo_id` para o último registro adicionado:

```
SELECT setval('Tabela1_novo_id_seq', Select MAX(id) from Tabela1);
```

Todas as referências estão nos links.